# Python 3.7 - Why am I receiving error for " in the following print with f command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Beginner here!

Code I am working with is:

```
my_name = 'Fake A. Name'
my_age = 20 # This is my real age
my_height = 72 # This is in inches
my_weight = 150 # Lbs
my_eyes = 'Blue'
my_teeth = 'White'
my_hair = 'Blonde'

print(f "Let's talk about {my_name}.")
```

Error Message:

```
print(f "Let'\s talk about {my_name}.")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am working through LPTHW (learn python the hard way) and despite following exact copy, am still receiving this error. I've tried searching through pythons rules but I am not finding much of a definite reason.

Answer (score 1):

There must not be any space between the `f` and the quotes, or it wouldn't be recognized as an f-string.

Change:

```
print(f "Let's talk about {my_name}.")
```

to:

```
print(f"Let's talk about {my_name}.")
```

Comment: When I do this it takes away the color formatting of the {my_name} variable and gives the same error points to quotes. Sorry should have stated that prior. Not sure if it is a difference in python3.6->7 or what - but I may want to also add that the command is performed fine in my terminal extension, just not within atom. Is this something I should be concerned about? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my atom is reading in a different version python, solved by a senior dev. within our company. Terminal runs fine and will be using that to read.

Comment: How come you consider yourself a beginner if you are working in a company, shouldn't you consider yourself as a junior developer?

Comment: @mahir My primary position in the company is not centered around tech or coding, more looking to build skills on the side.